# For $X_i\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, how to find the MSE of estimator: $\hat \sigma^2 = \frac 1{n+2}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2$.

Tags: statistics, estimation, decision-theory, mean-square-error

This is part of a larger problem. I have already found the MSE of two other estimators: $\hat\sigma_1^2 = \frac1{n-1}\sum_i^n (X_i-\bar X)^2$ and $\hat\sigma_2^2 = \frac1{n+1}\sum_i^n (X_i-\bar X)^2$. Now I need to find the MSE of $\frac1{n+2}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$.

I have tried breaking the problem down into $\text{MSE} = \text{Var} + \text{Bias}^2$, but I have been unable to find the variance. I am starting to think that I am not approaching this problem in the best way. Maybe I should somehow exploit the earlier results? Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: @BruceET I do know $Var(\hat\sigma_1^2)=\frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1}$, and can indeed find $Var(\sum(X_i-\bar X)^2)=(n-1)2\sigma^4$; but I still don't quite see how this gets me $Var(\hat \sigma^2)$ (assuming that you intended to put the hat over your final $\sigma$).

Comment: Right about var of sum not being sum of variances. I think I misread your question. Withdrawing comments. Except the mention of Lindgren's book.
More later if I have better suggestions.

Comment: Wider awake now and I've been pondering this: Are you sure the estimator $\hat \sigma^2$ of $\sigma$ isn't $\frac{1}{n+2}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i- \bar X)^2\,?$ The estimator $\frac{1}{n+2}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ would have a dist'n related to a 'non-central chi-squared distribution' (which you can google) and for large $\mu$ would be _grossly_ biased on the high side. // As I recall, it is interesting to compare MSEs of $\frac{1}{n+k}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2,$ for $k = -1, 0, 1, 2, 3.$

Comment: I'm not sure. This class does have as prerequisite a class that included cursory discussion of non-central $\chi^2$, but it seems unlikely to me that this question would be relying on that knowledge. Possibly it is a mistake.